# html form input value, will not echo php object function htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have implemented child classes to process user input inherited from a parent class which handles the database connections, read and write.

In my parent class I have a function called 'hsc' which handles 'htmlspecialchars' and the function filters user input and returns the string.

hsc function

```
public function hsc($string) {
    return htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

I am having a problem with my signup form. When I call the above function on the sign_up object, even before the form is submited the form breaks, then will only output the first label.

output

Your First Name (rest of the form is missing)

problem code

```
    value="<?php echo $sign_up->hsc($_POST['name']);?>" />
```

if I remove the above php code from value, the form displays correctly, also i can echo out text within the php tags, so the problem seems to be with the function?

While trying to figure this out, am I using the correct approach, ie, using classes too validate user input?

Hope someone can help

Thanks

please see the code I am using for the form below

```
    <?php
    include('./classes/signup_class.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//require('./classes/signup_class.php');
try {   
        $sign_up = new Signup_User();
        $sign_up->processUserInput();
        $errors = $sign_up->getErrorMessages();

    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
    ?>


    <form id="sign_up" method="post" action="">
<p>
<label for="name">Your First Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" 
    value="<?php echo   $sign_up->hsc($_POST['name']);?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="surname">Your Last Name</label>
<input name="surname" id="surname" type="text" /> 
</p>
<p>
<label for="email">Your Email Address</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="emailconf">Confirm Your Email Address</label>
<input name="emailconf" id="emailconf" type="text"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="gender">Your Gender</label>
<select class="gender_select" name="gender">
<option value="female">Female</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Choose Your Password (8 characters)</label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password">
</p>
<p>
<label for="passconf">Confirm Your Password</label>
<input name="passconf" id="passconf" type="password">
</p>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="signup" class="sign_up" >
    </form>
```

Comment: You have a fatal error in your script but you don't know which one it is. Enable PHP error reporting/logging/display, check your error log.

Comment: @hakre, I will do some investigating! , thanks!

Comment: I am now getting an error with the input fields on startup: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\includes\sign_up_inc.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br /> . It seems the form is trying to execute the php value code before the form is submitted. i have added a if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') to my hsc method however this does not work!!!

Comment: lol solved the problem I have amended form value to check for post I stupid of me to miss that! value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) {echo $sign_up->hsc($_POST['name']);}?>" /> I love learning, banging head!

Answer (score 1):

Here to have defined the class `new Signup_User();` in a condition that is true after submitting form.

try moving `$sign_up = new Signup_User();` before that if condition:-

```
$sign_up = new Signup_User();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//require('./classes/signup_class.php');
try {   
        $sign_up->processUserInput();
        $errors = $sign_up->getErrorMessages();

    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi sally, thanks for your response :) . I tried your suggestion and I have the same result, I also removed the try catch block, but the result is still the same!

Comment: sorry sally i moved the object creation out of the if statement. The form displays correctly, thanks! however the input field displays the following: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\includes\sign_up_inc.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

Comment: No problem Alan :), the simple fix will be:-

 `value="<?php if (isset($_POST)) echo $sign_up->hsc($_POST['name']);?>"`